# How can I make this method in Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Hlw!  I am a new comer in php , laravel can you explain that How Can I Creat this is `isAuthorized()`method with laravel Elouquet by replacing this query builder**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function isAuthorized($object, $operation)
    {
        return Db::table('role_permissions')
            ->where('object', $object)
            ->where('operation', $operation)
            ->join('user_roles', 'user_roles.role_id', '=', 'role_permissions.role_id')
            ->where('user_roles.user_id', $this->id)
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have here?

Comment: Eloquent uses Models, do you have models defined for these tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your Models like so.

```
public class RolePermission {
    public function UserRoles() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserRole::class, 'role_id', 'role_id');
    }
}

public class UserRole {

}
```

`WhereHas` can query relationships and is the cornerstone to replacing joins.

```
RolePermission::where('object', $object)
    ->where('operation', $operation)
    ->whereHas('UserRoles', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_roles.user_id', $this->id)
    })     
    ->exists();
```

Comment: Your relationtion data seemed a little funky, but i guess a one to many is the correct relation for user roles? :)

Comment: `user_roles` looks like a pivot table, having `user_id` and a `role_id`, but doesn't seem it is being used that way ... kinda hard to tell as you have mentioned :)